# how to sort tuple into timed intervals

Tags: python, list

I've got a list of tuples that need to be sorted into timed intervals in groups of a dependent variable

ie if I had the list

```
data_list = [(33, 60), (34, 64), (34, 1500), (34, 712), (35, 52), (35, 60), (36, 52), (36, 287), (37, 52), (37, 52), (37, 52), (39, 60), (40, 643), (40, 52)]
```

and `group = 5`
then we would have 5 different timed intervals ie

```
0-9,10-19,20-29,30-39,40-49
```

so the returned list would be `[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 12], [4, 2]]`
as there are 12 items in the range 30-39 and 2 items in the 40-49 range while the rest have none

I'm not sure where I could implement the group variable

```
    def get_freq_list(self):
        new_list = []
        n = 10
        a_list = ([self.__data_list[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(self.__data_list), n)])

        for i in range(len(a_list)):
            another_list = [i,len(a_list[i])
            new_list.append(another_list)

        return new_list
```

expected output would be `[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 12], [4, 2]]`

whilst I get `[[0, 10], [1, 4]]`

Comment: where are you actually counting elements from the list of tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work for you

```
data_list = [(33, 60), (34, 64), (34, 1500), (34, 712), (35, 52), (35, 60), (36, 52), (36, 287), (37, 52), (37, 52), (37, 52), (39, 60), (40, 643), (40, 52)]
q,w = zip(*data_list)
l=[]
for i in range(int(max(q)/10)+1):
    c=0
    for j in range(i*10,(i+1)*10):
        c+=q.count(j)
    l.append([i,c])
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

So... You're only looking at the first item in each tuple to determine the output? If so, the following should work. (You can discard the `interval` param if it will always be 10 and the `start` param if it will always be 0... just thought I'd put them in there...)

```
    def get_freq_list(self, n_groups=5, interval=10, start=0):
        output = []
        low = 0
        for i in range(n_groups):
            count = 0
            for tup in self.__data_list:
                if start < tup[0] and tup[0] < (low + interval):
                    count += 1
            output.append([i, count])
            low += interval
        return output
```

If you want to check both elements of the tuple, you can always add another `for` loop before the if statement like this:

```
...
            for tup in self.__data_list:
                for item in tup:
                    if start < item and item < (low + interval):
...
```